# google.com and youtube.com not working

Tags: dns

Trying to access google.com or youtube.com in  ANY browser (FF, chrome, ephiphany, w3m)
does not work ("could not find www.google.com").
I can ping both services with no problem.
Are there DNS problems again?

Answer (score 1):

If you ping by domain name and it is successful it is not DNS.

Try to wget the front page of google com:

```
wget http://google.com/
```

If you are able to successfully download the index.html page, you may have a browser issue.

Try to check the following:

- Proxy settings
- AD blocker settings (if any), or disable AD blocking

(Remark: corporate policies used to block entertainment sites during business hours...)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting network manager?  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Both google.com and youtube.com are blocked by system administrator. Contact him.